# Reading multiple CSV Files and add them to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, git, csv, glob

Hy Guys,
I m trying to import in a Dataframe many csv files.
I ve an error: Value error: No objects to concatenate

this is my code:

```
from glob import iglob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# read datas from github repository
path = r'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports'
df1 = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in iglob(path+"/*.csv", recursive=True)), ignore_index=True)
```

thanks for your help. If think it is due to path definition ?

Comment: You cannot glob a web path like this. You also should not use the CSV from github.com, because that is actually HTML. For the csv, use the raw file, for example https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-22-2020.csv

Comment: thanks so how can I get list of GitHub files ?

Comment: You can clone the repository and glob the files once they are on your computer. Because the files are dates, you can also create URLs based on date and use `pd.read_csv` on those URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates the dfs is empty hence the line pd.concat(dfs, ...) failed. So, I'm guessing the .csv files are not at where they are expected.

If you have the strange data folder structure, it should be able to load but it's hard for me to know as I can not see your folder structure.

Try this construction:

```
path =r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

dfs = []
for filename in filenames:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

df1 = pd.concat(dfs, recursive=True)), ignore_index=True)
```